# Aligning position absolute and margin: 0 auto; divs

Tags: html, css

I've spent way too long trying to work out how to do this!

I have two floated divs in a margin 0 auto container, top-left and top-right.

I have two absolute positioned divs that stick to either side of the window and meet each other at some point, bottom-left and bottom-right.

So my problem is, I want the meeting point of top-left and top-right divs to always be inline with the meeting point of bottom-left and bottom-right.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="top-left">Top Left</div>
 <div id="top-right">Top Right</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
<div id="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 70px;
  right: 45%;
}

#bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  height: 60px;
  left: 55%;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#top-left {
  width: 125px;
  float: left;
}

#top-right {
  width: 75px;
  float: left;
}
```

JS Fiddle of example http://jsfiddle.net/JECyC/1/ If you change size of the window, the meeting points drift apart!

I may be approaching this in the wrong way, so I'm open to a completely different solution!

Cheers.

Edit 1:
Screenshot, I need to make sure that the divs corners always meet.

[image: test]

Comment: can you post the screenshot of required output?

Comment: that's because the left and right are not 50%, it's "normal" that they drift because of the 5% difference.

Comment: I've put a screenshot in the main post.

Comment: jackJoe, do you know another way to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

```
#top-left {
  background-color:yellow;
  width:68%;
  float:left;
}

#top-right {
  background-color:blue;
  width:32%;
  float:left;
}
```

Something like this ... I just don't see another way.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but this still seems to suffer from the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

use  this code  i hope this will help for u

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div style="width:900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<div  style=" width:450; height:70px;  background:yellow; float:left;">top left</div>
<div  style=" width:450; height:70px;  background:green; float:right;">top right</div>
</div>
<div  style="width:900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
<div  style=" width:450; height:70px; background:red; float:left;">botom left</div>
<div  style=" width:450; height:70px; background:blue; float:right;">bottom right</div>
</div>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it still seems to have the same issue when resizing the window.

Comment: That doesn't do it, the bottom two divs need to expand to the edge of the window and also not use a 50% width.

Answer (score 0):

Your top-left and top-right have fixed width but bottom-left and bottom-right have variable width . so they will never be inline as if u keep reducing window size, top divs will be as it is and size of bottom divs will keep reducing so there will be point when both bottom divs have width equal to single top div n other div is not visible due to scrollbar.

[image: demo]

You can try applying fixed width and margin auto to bottom div as u did with top div . if u want them always be inline.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the problem is I need the bottom left and right divs to always touch the sides of the window.